# cannot find a way to download the right pakage to change my aarch64 to a 32 bit system

Tags: 64-bit, steam

I have tryed to download so many seperate packages in order to get steam on my lennovo chromebook. i have activated linux and i have updated it about 5 times so im sure its current but it can't find any of the pakages these online articles tell me to punch in. can it be done or is it not possiple. someone help.

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details.   To switch the main architecture; you need to reinstall.  Have you tried https://ubuntu.com/download

Answer (score 2):

You cannot convert a 64-bit Ubuntu installation to a 32-bit Ubuntu installation.

You will need to reinstall the operating system with the desired version.

Comment: thanks for the help but im new to all of this its amazing i made it this far. can you explain how to do that.

Comment: There are so many guides for installing Ubuntu including the official [tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop) from Canonical. But are you sure you even need the 32-bit version of Ubuntu? Steam works just fine on 64-bit versions. I think you have asked an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).  You should ask about the actual problem you are experiencing and provide details about that problem. If you ask about your proposed solution, it may not solve the actual problem you have.

Comment: For basic tasks like creating installation media and installing Ubuntu, there are [tutorials](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials) maintained by Canonical.  I'm not sure why you would have needed to update 5 times unless you are installing a very outdated version of Ubuntu. Don't follow guides that are very old and haven't been updated in a long time and don't follow guides that lack authority.  If you are confused about something, ask a new question and make sure you tell us what guide you are following and exactly where you are stuck/confused. Provide all relevant details like error messages

Comment: Steam is easily installed using the Software Center which is very user friendly and essentially the same as using the Windows Store, Apple's App Store, and Google Play.  So if you're doing anything more than this or you're having problems, you should ask about those problems and provide more details and context about what you are doing

Comment: Thank you so much for all the suport its good to now that there is a comunity of people willing to help out.

Comment: i have activated linux ... What does this mean what Ubuntu are you running?